# TemplateBuilder _preprocess - generate new guid as value

Tags: sidewaffle

I am using sidewaffle TemplateBuilder to create a multi project solution.
In one of my projects i have a GUID i would like to change during _preprocess generating a new GUID in its place. Something like:

```
 add key="base(new
 Guid(&quot;{34BC9328-FC0D-4960-83B2-612B13DE1514}&quot;))"
 value="base(new Guid(&quot;MYNEWGUIDHERE&quot;))"/>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, after posting this question, with some new angles and testing. I found the answer. It is easier than one would think.

There are mechanisms for doing this built in to template generation.
More info on them check here [Template Parameters.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx)

But in short you can use `$guid1$` to `$guid10$` getting up to 10 unique GUID's.
It would look like this in my _preprocess file:

```
 <add key="base(new Guid(&quot;{34BC9328-FC0D-4960-83B2-612B13DE1514}&quot;))" value="base(new Guid(&quot;$guid1$&quot;))"/>
```

It is as simple as that :)